# How to copy azure blobs to sftp server using java by converting it into stream

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Please find below code snippet for what i am trying to do.

```
public static void main(){

        final String CONNECTION_STRING_SRC = "......";
        final String SOURCE_CONTAINER = "decrypted";
        final String FILE_CONTAINER = "callinteractiondata";
        // Connecting to the source Storage Account (ccdmrecordinginbound)
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient1 = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(CONNECTION_STRING_SRC).buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient srcContainer = blobServiceClient1.getBlobContainerClient(SOURCE_CONTAINER);
        logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE,"Connected to the source container");
        //System.out.println("Connected to the source container");
        String blobName ="TestMP3 files";
        BlobClient sourceBlobClient = srcContainer.getBlobClient(blobName);
        // From this point onwards, I need to copy source blob to sftp directly without copying in local. 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow the below Prerequisites and steps to build your code.

**Prerequisites**

If your data store is a managed cloud data service, you can use the Azure Integration Runtime. If the access is restricted to IPs that are approved in the firewall rules, you can add [Azure Integration Runtime IPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses) to the allow list.

Steps for copy the azure blobs to sftp server using java with the help of Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics

Step 1: Create an SFTP linked service in your Azure Data Factory or Synapse workspace

Step 2: Configure the service details, test the connection, and create the new linked service.

Step 3: Select Authentication type basic, SSH public key authentication or multifactor authentication.

Step 4: Set the Azure Data Factory file format ex: JSON, XML,EXCEL

Step 5: Perform the copy activity SFTP as destination.

Step 6: Final perform the SFTP as a sink.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp?tabs=data-factory

Comment: I am already aware of these steps, I was looking in case anybody directly handled it in any APIs using java.